# Visual Studio On Mac Models Missing Fields

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 on MAC, developing Xamarin.iOS app and I'm facing weird issue.

- I have PCL where I have created HttpClient with its models (request & response of each API call).
- I'm using the models from PCL (initializing & assign values) to generate the post request object from Xamarin.iOS app.
- I'm calling the post method from Xamarin.iOS app
- Now I'm getting the post request object is always null in the PCL!! and when reading as string it is `{}`
- Then I'm trying to trace the issue with one of models (contains `EmailAddress` and `FullName`), so added `Console.WriteLine(searchRequest.EmailAddress)` in Xamarin.iOS app before calling client post method (just to know where is the source of this issue)
- Now In PCL, I'm getting only the `EmailAddress` field `{"EmailAddress" : "sample@domain.com"}`
- And After I tried to add `Console.WriteLine(searchRequest.FullName)` I'm able to get the proper object  `{"EmailAddress" : "sample@domain.com", "FullName" : "Sample Full Name"}`!!!

**Request from Xamarin.iOS app:**

```
APIClient client = new APIClient();
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
  EmailAddress = "sample@domain.com",
  FullName = "Sample Full Name"
};
var result = await client.Search(searchRequest);
```

**PCL Client Model Object:**

```
public class SearchRequest
{
public string FullName {get; set;}
public string EmailAddress {get;set}
}
```

**PCL HTTP Client:**

```
public async Task<SearchResult> Search(SearchRequest requestObj)
{
    SearchResult res = new SearchResult();
    StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObj, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); // Content as string will be {}
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"{baseURL}ApplicationSearch", content);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(responseString);
}
```

And just if I add the following two lines in Xmarin.iOS app after `var result = await client.Search(searchRequest);` :

```
Console.WriteLine(searchRequest.EmailAddress);
Console.WriteLine(searchRequest.FullName);
```

Now the `StringContent` object will have:

```
{"EmailAddress" : "sample@domain.com", "FullName" : "Sample Full Name"}
```

**Can Anybody please explain what's going on here ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your Xamarin.iOS app is built, it runs through a linker for managed code that strips out unused code, that is never accessed to reduce the application size. In your case the properties were never accessed directly, only by reflection in `Json.Net`.

But when you accessed the properties at least once, they were included in the resulting binary and as a result the `Json.Net` can find them.

To make sure your custom class members are preserved even if not accessed directly, you can add a `Preserve` attribute to your class:

```
[Preserve(AllMembers=true)]
public class SearchRequest
{
   ...
}
```

You might need this attribute inside your PCL as well. Luckily, you can define it yourself manually, as the linker just looks for the attribute by name:

```
public sealed class PreserveAttribute : System.Attribute {
    public bool AllMembers;
    public bool Conditional;
}
```

You can see more details regarding this topic in the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/).